# Get rid of blue line

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

With the help of ActionBarSherlock I try to get my app running on pre 3.0 devices. There is a blue divider in the action bar, which I want to have removed.

[image: strange blue line]

I figured out that it isn't a divider, but part of the background graphic of the action bar. To get rid of the blue line I decided to override the background like this:

```
 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/black</item>
   <item name="background">@drawable/black</item>
 </style>
```

I also set the background in the Java code:

```
getSupportActionBar().setStackedBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black));
```

As a result the blue line disappears on 4.x devices, but is still visible on 2.3.x devices. How do I get rid of the blue line on 2.3.x devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake: I used `setStackedBackgroundDrawable` instead of `setBackgroundDrawable`. It works fine with `setBackgroundDrawable`. This is the correct method to set the background of the action bar. `setStackedBackgroundDrawable` sets the background of the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the blue line is part of the TabWidget you have there... But if it isn't you can have a look at this webpage: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

It's a really good Action Bar style generator. Worth a try :)

Comment: I don't think that the blue line is part of the TabWidget, because if so, my approach wouldn't work on 4.x devices.

Answer (score 0):

**actionBarDivider** attribute belongs to the theme
Remove it like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
 </style>
```